# First time starting Tor Browser after reboot always result in "Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection"

Tags: configuration, error

on my system Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit I have used Tor Browser for years. Currently I am using the latest officially stable version 7.0.1. I use bridge **meek-azure** if this is in some importance.

When ever I start "Tor Browser" dialog "Connecting to Tor network appears" (which is fine), but after a second I ALWAYS get error:

```
Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection. Establishing an
encrypted directory connection failed (done - 0.0.2.0:3)
```

Then I click on OK button and "Tor Network Settings" dialog appears. I click on Connect button and dialog with "Remove Settings and Connect" button appears. When pressing this button Tor Browser starts in a about two seconds and working perfectly fine.

This kind of behavior (first time fail and after "Remove Settings and Connect" button) ALWAYS happens. When I reboot Ubuntu and start Tor Browser above error appears, or if I close down perfectly working Tor Browser and start it again. First time it ALWAYS result in above error and "Remove Settings and Connect" dialog button ALWAYS solves the problem.

It is not a big problem, just a pretty annoying way of starting Tor Browser.

Bellow is log file copied from inside of Tor Browser on Tor green button and Tor Network Settings.

```
18. 06. 2017 11:59:30.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
18. 06. 2017 11:59:30.000 [NOTICE] Switching to guard context "bridges" (was using "default") 
18. 06. 2017 11:59:30.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
18. 06. 2017 11:59:32.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
18. 06. 2017 11:59:32.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
18. 06. 2017 11:59:32.900 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 1; recommendation warn; host 97700DFE9F483596DDA6264C4D7DF7641E1E39CE at 0.0.2.0:3) 
18. 06. 2017 11:59:32.900 [WARN] 1 connections have failed: 
18. 06. 2017 11:59:32.900 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
18. 06. 2017 11:59:37.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
18. 06. 2017 11:59:37.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
18. 06. 2017 11:59:37.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
18. 06. 2017 12:00:33.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
18. 06. 2017 12:00:33.300 [NOTICE] Switching to guard context "default" (was using "bridges") 
18. 06. 2017 12:00:33.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
18. 06. 2017 12:00:33.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
18. 06. 2017 12:00:33.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
18. 06. 2017 12:00:33.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network 
18. 06. 2017 12:00:33.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop 
18. 06. 2017 12:00:34.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit 
18. 06. 2017 12:00:34.700 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working. 
18. 06. 2017 12:00:34.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done 
18. 06. 2017 12:00:37.200 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
18. 06. 2017 12:00:37.300 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
```

Any idea what is causing this behaviour?
Thanks

Comment: You don't need bridges. You're connecting fine without them: `18. 06. 2017 12:00:33.300 [NOTICE] Switching to guard context "default" (was using "bridges")`. Possibly your ISP doesn't like Azure but isn't blocking Tor or some other combination.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what is the problem. I am using [firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/) sandbox application with command:

```
firejail /path/start-tor-browser
```

and closing down Tor browser and starting again with about command produces error from my question.

Using command without firejail like:

```
 /path/start-tor-browser
```

and Tor browser is started without a problem every time.